# Garden with St. Augustine grass has some damaged areas (lot of rain activity later). What could be causing the issue?

Tags: grass, slugs

I have a garden with St. Augustine grass. A week ago I started seeing some damaged area. There has been a lot of rain activity in my zone lately, so I don't know if the reason is excess of water or maybe slugs that come afterwards because of the humidity.

**Complete view of the garden:**
[image: garden]

**Healthy area:**
[image: healthy area]

**Example of damaged area:**
[image: damaged area]

What could be causing the issue? Does anybody have any ideas for solutions? Thanks!